# R axis subscribt dataframe

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, axis

My axis is automatically called after my data frame and I would like to have the _all
from ST_all as subscript. How do I implement *expression()* without breaking the data frame?

```
boxplot(data.frame(ST_all=CV_STrel$STrel*100,ST=c(CV_STrelMLTS$STrel,NA,NA)*100,F_all=CV_Frel$Frel*100,F=c(CV_FrelMLTS$Frel,NA,NA)*100,IM_all=CV_IMrel$IMrel*100,IM=c(CV_IMrelMLTS$IMrel,NA,NA)*100,L_all=CV_Lrel$Lrel*100,L=c(CV_LrelMLTS$Lrel,NA,NA)*100),cex.lab=1,ylab="CV [%]",col=gray((1:8)/10),outline=TRUE,ylim=c(0,14))
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, I'd sure appreciate a *minimal* working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [image: plot]

```
set.seed(1);
N <- 20;
low <- 0;
high <- 14/100;
CV_STrel <- data.frame(STrel=runif(N,low,high));
CV_STrelMLTS <- data.frame(STrel=runif(N-2,low,high));
CV_Frel <- data.frame(Frel=runif(N,low,high));
CV_FrelMLTS <- data.frame(Frel=runif(N-2,low,high));
CV_IMrel <- data.frame(IMrel=runif(N,low,high));
CV_IMrelMLTS <- data.frame(IMrel=runif(N-2,low,high));
CV_Lrel <- data.frame(Lrel=runif(N,low,high));
CV_LrelMLTS <- data.frame(Lrel=runif(N-2,low,high));

pd <- data.frame(
    ST_all=CV_STrel$STrel*100,
    ST=c(CV_STrelMLTS$STrel,NA,NA)*100,
    F_all=CV_Frel$Frel*100,
    F=c(CV_FrelMLTS$Frel,NA,NA)*100,
    IM_all=CV_IMrel$IMrel*100,
    IM=c(CV_IMrelMLTS$IMrel,NA,NA)*100,
    L_all=CV_Lrel$Lrel*100,
    L=c(CV_LrelMLTS$Lrel,NA,NA)*100
);

boxplot(
    pd,
    cex.lab=1,
    ylab="CV [%]",
    col=gray((1:8)/10),
    outline=TRUE,
    ylim=c(0,14),
    axes=F
);
axis(1,at=seq_along(pd),labels=parse(text=sub(perl=T,'_(.*)','[\\1]',names(pd))));
axis(2);
```

Comment: thank you very much. looks a charm! i guess 1-liners can only get you so far.